# Number of years to file US expat taxes using Streamlined Procedure

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, foreign-income

I live outside of the US and will be using Streamlined Foreign Offshore Procedures to file taxes, which requires filing for the most recent 3 years for which the deadline has passed.

Since the deadline for expats to file taxes this year is mid-June, this means I need to file for 2012, 2013, 2014 (with the streamlined procedure), as well as for 2015, and provide FBAR statements for the previous 6 years plus the current year (2008-2015), is that correct?

What if I were to wait until this year's deadline has passed so I wouldn't have to bother filing for 2012? Would that be ok? I know it's probably frowned upon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deadline for FBAR filing is June 30th, by that time the FBAR must be *received* by FinCEN. It is no longer filed by mail, but you still need to e-file it before June ends. So if you're using the streamlined procedure (i.e.: filing the current and all the delinquent), I don't think you can be late.

For tax returns, the statute of limitations doesn't kick in until the return is filed, so I suggest filing it. Although if you wait past June 15th you may claim that "3 years back is until 2013", in practice it may invalidate the whole "streamlined procedure" thing and you'll end up coughing up all the penalties. Unless there's something to hide there (in which case talk to an attorney), I'd suggest not playing this game.